# foreach с определенными данными

Tags: php, html, массивы, foreach

Имею массив такой:

```
$names = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'country' => 'Russia',
        'lang' => 'Russian',
        'img' => 'assets/img/radiolang/rus.png',
        'link' => '/r/russian'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'country' => 'Egland',
        'lang' => 'English',
        'img' => 'assets/img/radiolang/eng.png',
        'link' => '/r/english'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'country' => 'Spain',
        'lang' => 'Spanish',
        'img' => 'assets/img/radiolang/esp.png',
        'link' => '/r/spanish'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'country' => 'Netherlands',
        'lang' => 'Dutch',
        'img' => 'assets/img/radiolang/dutch.png',
        'link' => '/r/dutch'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'country' => 'Ukraine',
        'lang' => 'Ukrainian',
        'img' => 'assets/img/radiolang/ukr.png',
        'link' => '/r/ukrainian'
    ],
];
```

Так вот, я хочу отобразить на index.php (путем include) так чтобы оно мне отобразила через foreach(Если есть другой вариант то его тоже можно) только ID 1, 2 и 3.

На данный момент у меня так в template.php:

```
<?php foreach ($names as $name): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $name['link']; ?>"><img id="radioimg" src="<?php echo $name['img']; ?>"></img></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: уточните, вам нужны только id 1,2,3 или первые три элемента? равнозначные ли это задачи?

Comment: если данные из БД - то выбери первые три и всё....если еще откуда, то примени `array_splice` или `array_slice`

Comment: @teran первые три элемента которые имеют данные. Я не совсем понял вопрос про "равнозначные ли это задачи?"

Comment: $names = array_filter($names,function($val){
 if($val['id'] <= 3)
  return $val;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($names);

или в foreach прописать следующее if($name['id'] > 3) continue;

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan еще вопрос, как сделать чтобы в if($val['id'] <= 3, было от 3 до 6 допустим

Comment: @Jengas 3,4,5,6 ?  if($val['id'] >= 3 && $val['id'] <= 6); если тройка не нужна уберите знак равенства перед ним (> 3)

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan `array_filter($names,function($val){ if($val['id'] <= 3) return $val; }); echo '<pre>'; print_r($names); или в foreach прописать следующее if($name['id'] > 3) continue;` -  если элементов 100,200 - то 
 зачем гонять вхолостую циклы?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пока-что у меня 10 элементов. В будущем будет около 40. Есть какие-то есть идеи как сделать чтобы не гонят вхолостую циклы?

Comment: @Jengas второй комментарий сверху

Comment: Это скорее всего результат выборки из базы где можно всегда следит за количеством результата.Хотя верно подмечено что если данные будут больше то так делать не стоит.А если 5-10 то мои вариант.если нет то надо кучу вещей уточнять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//  $name это ваш массив
    function filterMyArray($var) {
        return (in_array($var['id'],[1,2,3]));
    }
    $arr = array_filter($name, "filterMyArray");
    print_r($arr); //тут будет массив только с id 1,2,3
```